# Confusion over configuration space, workspace and task space

Tags: kinematics

I have been watching Kevin Lynch's videos on Coursera in [this series](https://www.coursera.org/learn/modernrobotics-course1/lecture/RtkAq/task-space-and-workspace-chapter-2-5) on the basics of robotics. From that I gathered these are the definitions.

> configuration space is the space of all configurations of the robot.

> workspace is a specification of the configurations that the end-effector of the robot can reach

> task space is a space in which the robot's task can be naturally expressed

- Is the workspace contained in the configuration space since the end-effector is part of the robot? I understand that the configuration space is for each rigid link of the robot from [this answer](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/2422/is-configuration-space-same-as-joint-space#answer-2444) and the end-effector is a link.
- Is it possible to have a task space that is beyond the configuration space?

Answer (score 4):

Two of these terms describe mathematical spaces (Configuration and Task spaces), and one (Workspace) the physical space in which the robot operates. Acknowledging they are related, but they are not the same "type of thing".

I recommend having a look at the *QUT Robot academy* videos by Peter Corke:

- [Task and Configuration Space](https://robotacademy.net.au/lesson/task-and-configuration-space/)
- and [Robot Workspace](https://robotacademy.net.au/lesson/robot-workspace/).

Which define **configuration space** as the mathematical set of all possible joint configurations. **Task space** the mathematical set of all possible end effector poses. And, **workspace** as the physical volume of all reachable end point positions".

No I don't believe it's possible to have a task space "beyond" the configuration space.

Comment: Are **end point positions** different from **end effector poses**?

Comment: Yes I believe so. Some positions/locations  can be achieved by a variety of effector poses.

Comment: I am confused now. What's meant by **end point positions**? The final configuration of the robot?

Comment: The understanding I have taken away (and I am not an expert, so please check) is that end point positions are a position in physical space. The workspace that the robot arm can reach. For some end points at the extremities of the workspace there may be only one configuration of the arm and effector (I.e, end effector pose) that can reach that point. For other points there may be multiple poses that reach the one spot.

Comment: As an analogy, think of a point in front of your chest and quite close, and one of your arms as the robot arm. You can reach the point with your shoulder joint and elbow arcing up high and your hand and wrist coming downwards to the point, alternatively you can reach the point with your shoulder and elbow arcing downwards and your hand and wrist coming upwards to the same point. For an end point that is well inside your workspace there are multiple  poses that can reach there. For a point at the maximum stretch of your arm there might be only one pose you can physically achieve to get there.